# Stylesheet could not be loaded

Tags: css, fonts

I try to load in style.css this code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Roboto+Slab');
```

but i receive this error:

```
Stylesheet could not be loaded https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Roboto+Slab
```

Somehow you know what is wrong?is a syntax error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine in here, see the example ([@import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%40import))

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Roboto+Slab');

.Karla {
    font-family: Karla;
}

.Roboto_Slab {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab'; 
}
```

```html
<div class="Karla">Karla</div>
<div class="Roboto_Slab">Roboto Slab</div>
<div>Normal</div>
```

You could also load it the "old fashioned way" via

```css
.Karla {
    font-family: Karla;
}

.Roboto_Slab {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab'; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Roboto+Slab" />

<div class="Karla">Karla</div>
<div class="Roboto_Slab">Roboto Slab</div>
<div>Normal</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code you are using. If you are using `@import`, you need to make sure that it's at the very top of the CSS document. Alternatively, you could use `<link>` in the `<head>` and load **Google Fonts** using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla|Roboto+Slab" />
```

Comment: With CSS, cant you import it at the bottom to overwrite whats above it?

Comment: `@import` rules must precede all other types of rules, except `@charset` rules; as it is not a nested statement. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) for more information about `@import`.